# Intel Advisor beta offloading analysis: No execution count

Tags: intel, offloading, intel-advisor, intel-oneapi

I am trying to use Intel oneAPI advisor beta to do a GPU offloading analysis (via `analyze.py` and `collect.py`). I have the problem that all non offloaded regions show `Cannot be modelled: No Execution Count`.

Furthermore I get the warning

```
advixe: Warning: A symbol file is not found. The call stack passing through `...../programm.out' module may be incorrect.
```

I've already tried the troubleshooting described [here](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/advisor-user-guide/top/offload-advisor/offload-advisor-troubleshooting/offload-advisor-troubleshooting-why-not-offloaded/offload-advisor-troubleshooting-cannot-be-modeled.html) and [here](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/advisor-user-guide/top/offload-advisor/offload-advisor-troubleshooting/offload-advisor-troubleshooting-broken-call-tree.html). Moreover I tried using a programm with larger runtime.

I compiled with the compiler flags (according to [this](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/advisor-user-guide/top/offload-advisor/offload-advisor-before-you-begin.html)) (notice that debugging information is turned on):

```
-O2 -std=c++11 -fopenmp -g -no-ipo -debug inline-debug-info
```

I am using *Intel(R) Advisor 2021.1 beta07 (build 606302)*,  and *Intel(R) C Intel(R) 64 Compiler for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 2021.1 Beta Build 202006*. The program uses OpenMP.

What could I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurred because the **program had too large a workload** / the memory of the machine was not sufficient.

Try

- running collect.py with `--no-track-heap-objects` (might reduce precision)
- reducing the runtime and memory usage of the program that is analysed
- [pausing and resuming only on relevant parts](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/advisor-user-guide/top/offload-advisor/offload-advisor-minimize-collection-overhead/offload-advisor-pause-resume-collection-using-api-methods.html) via the libittnotify API

Comment: Also see the [relevant thread in the Intel forum](https://community.intel.com/t5/Analyzers-Intel-VTune-Profiler/Offloading-analysis-no-execution-count-already-tried/m-p/1195694#M19136)